# Issues with FTPS connection on port 990 in VScode

Tags: visual-studio-code, ftps

I'm trying to setup my FTP in VSCode using the sftp extension but I can't get it to connect, it says it's timing out every time. The issue is that my SFTP config from sublime text has always worked on this specific server (ftps connection using port 990). Never had a single issue.

The config that has been working on sublime text:

```
"type": "ftps",

    "save_before_upload": true,
    "upload_on_save": true,
  
    "host": "ftpweb.user.srv",
    "user": "ftpweb.user.srv|user1",
    "password": "redacted",
    "port": "990",
    
    "remote_path": "/",

    "connect_timeout": 5,
    "keepalive": 120,
    "ftp_passive_mode": true,
    "ftp_obey_passive_host": true,
    "allow_config_upload": true,
```

new config for VScode that is timing out:

```
{
    "name": "test",
    "host": "ftpweb.user.srv",
    "protocol": "ftp",
    "secure": true,
    "secureOptions": {
        "rejectUnauthorized": false
    },
    "port": 990,
    "username": "ftpweb.user.srv|user1",
    "password": "redacted",
    "remotepath": "/",
    "uploadOnSave": true
}
```

What am I missing in VScode? I know it doesn't truly support ftps but I thought there would be a workaround using ftp, I just can't seem to find any loophole here. Has anyone been able to connect to a FTPS server on port 990 in VSCode?

Comment: SFTP and FTPS are **completely** different protocols.

Answer (score -1):

I believe you just need to correct remotePath (not remotepath)

```
"remotePath": "/",
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).